# Vector iterators incompatible in assignment overload

Tags: c++, vector

Simple problem here. I'm dealing with a bit of an issue of assignment here with vectors.
I have one class, Inventory:

```
class Inventory
{
public:
    __inline void operator=( const Inventory& rtSide )
    {
        items.clear();
        for(auto it=rtSide.items.begin(); it!=rtSide.items.end(); ++it)
        {
            items.push_back(*it);
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<void*> items;
}
```

There's a struct that contains the class:

```
typedef struct
{
    Inventory *inventory;
} player_t;
```

Upon assigning/doing pointer math on a pointer of player_t, Inventory's = overload gets called, as you would expect. However, using MSVC, it would appear that there's an assertion failure, specifically, "vector iterators incompatible". The weird thing is, this happens on the clear(). I have no idea what's goin on here. If someone could give me some assistance that would be great.

Here's an example of what's going on. Using pointer math, we can determine the client number by subtracting the current client's player structure from the base:

```
clientNum = newcl - svs.clients;
```

This specifically is what is causing me to assert.

Comment: Do you know what `items.clear()` does? Your loop doesn't run.

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: rtSide.items.begin() , items is a private variable to directly access like this ?

Comment: @jayadev: Yes, Class A can access private members of other Class A instances. Private only means that "other classes can't touch this". It's not about instances of the class.

Comment: without knowing which compiler you use: `__inline` is (highly probably) unecessary. a) member functions defined in their class are always `inline`, b) the sanctioned keyword is `inline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your pointer arithmetic resulted in attempting to call the assignment operator on an `Inventory`, but the pointer did not in fact point to an `Inventory`. (e.g. it may point to a `delete`'d `Inventory`) If that was the case, `vector`'s guts could be filled with random garbage, which could cause these kinds of assertion failures.

For instance, your the caller might do the moral equivalent of:

```
Inventory out;
Inventory* target = nullptr;
*target = out;
```

which could cause these kinds of assertion failures. Check the code calling the assignment operator.

(Also note that your assignment operator doesn't handle assignment to self; but in that case it will just clear the `Inventory`, not cause assertion failures)

Comment: This looks to be the case. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want to copy the items from the `rtSide` list, not the ones in `this`.

```
    items.clear();
    for(auto it=rtSide.items.begin(); it!=rtSide.items.end(); ++it)
    {
        items.push_back(*it);
    }
```

(Of course, the compiler will generate this code for you if you don't write your own `operator=`, and you can also copy a vector by `items = rtSide.items;` - my point with the post was more to point out that "there is nothing wrong with your iterators, you are just not copying the right thing").

And I would also say that using a `vector<void *>` is pretty much "using C++ in a C way". You should store at least a pointer to a base-class, if not a smart pointer to a base-class. Baseclass could be something like "inventry_item" or something like that.

(And I believe `xxxx_t` types are reserved for POSIX, so you shouldn't really call your types `xxxx_t`)

Comment: Or just `items = rtSide.items;` Or even better, just let the compiler generated assignment operator do its thing :)

Comment: Thank you, I will make the changes. However, that doesn't fix the issue. It still asserts on items.clear();

Comment: It will have to be a more complete example that that - something that can be compiled on my machine (or someone else's).

Comment: (Of course, "reserved for posix" is only relevant if you are targeting posix. Neither C nor C++ reserve any such thing)

Comment: @BillyONeal: That may be true, but you never know where/when your code will be "needed" in some other environment than the one you originally considered it for. And more importantly, if you pick up that as a habit, you may do it without thinking in a place where it is indeed targetting a posix system.

Comment: @Mats: That may be true, but it is unreasonable to code for every possible intersection of every reserved thing. Windows reserves the name "CreateWindow", but I wouldn't expect POSIX code to avoid that name. Just as I wouldn't expect Windows code to avoid the name "stat".

Comment: The `_t` is generally avoided by MS tho (other than when it's used in conjunction with Posix compatible calls, such as `time_t`. And I'm not sure what reason MS has for calling their function `_stat` - to show the difference, or just to make it harder to compile generic code in a Windows environment.